# Multiplication variables in IReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to create a variable in **IReport**  that multiplies two values. I wonder what can i give in the calculation column while creating the variable ? pl help

Comment: You can look at [Using report variables](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-variables) post

Comment: I tried the following 
`<variable name="Cumulative Cost" class="java.lang.Float">
<variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Fsum}*.50]]></variableExpression>
<initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>`

Comment: The `$V{Fsum}` is another variable. anybody pl help

Comment: Make sure $V{Fsum} is declared before $V{Cumulative Cost}

Comment: off course it is. cant we create a variable to multiply a variable and a value  ?

Comment: I get the following error if set the calculation type to "Nothing"

`Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      Source text : $V{Cumulative Cost} 
Setting up the file resolver...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float `
Nothing i have declared as double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.50 - is a double
Replace expression to $V{Fsum}* .50f